# Is it possible to disable all links in received text messages?

Tags: iphone, messages

My elderly mother got phished. Luckily, I got to the message before she did. The message just said

> *Sur La Table blah blah blah* [link](http://example.com).

I would like that to just be:

> *Sur La Table blah blah blah* example.com

What I'd like is for that link to just be text, no link. That way it would be difficult for her to accidentally or impulsively tap on it. Is there any way to do this?

NB: this is not the same as settings -> Siri and search -> messages, turn off Siri&suggestions

Comment: Links in Messages get rendered by the app automatically, there might not be a setting to prevent that.